# Akka Streams Kafka - unit test for consumer

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, akka, akka-stream, reactive-kafka

I've tried to test my code locally by setting up a Kafka server and sending messages using a producer, but I am wondering if there is a way I can write a unit test for this piece of code (test whether the message received by the consumer is correct).

```
val consumerSettings = ConsumerSettings(system, 
  new ByteArrayDeserializer, new StringDeserializer)
  .withBootstrapServers("localhost:9092")
  .withGroupId("group1")
  .withProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest")

val done = Consumer.committableSource(consumerSettings, 
  Subscriptions.topics("topic1"))
  .map { msg =>
    msg.committableOffset.commitScaladsl()
  }
  .runWith(Sink.ignore)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could test your code with the following tools:

- ScalaTest
- [scalatest-embedded-kafka](https://github.com/manub/scalatest-embedded-kafka): enables the creation of an in-memory Kafka instance that works with ScalaTest.
- [Akka Streams Testkit](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/scala/stream/stream-testkit.html#streams-testkit): provides a `TestSink.probe` that can inspect, and control the demand of, stream elements (i.e., messages).

The Akka Streams Kafka project uses the above in its own tests. Take a look at its [`IntegrationSpec`](https://github.com/akka/reactive-kafka/blob/v0.17/core/src/test/scala/akka/kafka/scaladsl/IntegrationSpec.scala), which you can adapt for your needs.